# Change class of a D3 map's tooltip with mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I recently made [an interactive map](http://raphi.m0le.net/data/FN%201995%202012/fn_1995.html) using D3js and the plugin d3.tip.js to code a nice tooltip. I wrote these line for the tooltip's style :

```
.d3-tip {  

  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.9);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 11px!important;

  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 205px;
}
```

The margin-left and margin-top attributes made the tooltip appear under the mouse cursos like this :[image: The tooltip]

The tooltip works fine for the large majority of my areas, but there is an issue with the top right of the iframe, like this :

[image: The tooltip issue]

So I was wondering if I can apply an other class, with a different margin-left value, by testing the x position of the mouse in the iframe.

If the x position is after my limit, the tooltip goes more on cursor's left, else it goes more to the right.

Do you think these is it possible ? I searched without finding anything which I could adapt. Here's [a link to fork all the code in gitHub](https://github.com/raphadasilva/Carte-D3).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the classes on the tip element in your event handler function.  Instead of passing `tip.show` directly to the mouseover event, you can create your own event handler that calculates whether the tip needs to be re-positioned, sets the classes accordingly, and also calls `tip.show()` with the correct parameters.

Things to be aware of:

- `d3.tip` doesn't implement the `classed()` method to toggle individual classes, so you have to reset the entire class attribute.
- `tip.show()` resets the default classes itself, so you need to set your custom classes **after** you show the tip.
- You need to pass the `d,i` variables to `tip.show()` if they are going to be used in the html update function.

A simplified example follows.  The tips show up at the top edge of the rectangles by default, I check whether that would push the tip off the top edge of the page, and set a class to translate the tip if so.

```js
/* Initialize tooltip */
tip = d3.tip()
  .html(function(d, i) { return "Rectangle #" + i; });

/* Invoke the tip in the context of your visualization */
vis = d3.select("svg")
vis.call(tip)

vis.selectAll('rect')
  .datum(function(d){ 
    //save the old data (null in this example)
    //as a sub-property of a new data object
    //which also contains position information
    return {data:d, position:(this.x, this.y)}; 
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d, i){
    //save the moused-over graphical element in a variable
    var rect = this;
  
    tip.show(d, i); //show the tip (will call the .html function)
  
    tip.attr('class', function(){
      //use the properties of the moused-over element
      //to modify the classes on the tip object:
      if (rect.getBBox().y < 50)
        return 'd3-tip n down'
      else
        return 'd3-tip n';
    })
  })
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

```css
rect {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: blue;
}

.d3-tip {
  background: white;
  border: solid gray;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
.d3-tip.down {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 2em);
  transform: translate(0, 2em);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.6.3/d3-tip.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400px" height="400px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```